# MySQL timestamp to .NET timestamp

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, linq, types, dblinq

I am using DBLinq to access a MySQL DB from C# .NET 3.5

I have created the dbml file for the Visual Studio 2010 ORM, and it loads fine - however when I compile the source I am met with errors regarding the conversion of MySQL timestamp to .NET DateTime.

Now this kind of makes sense, because they are 2 'different' types (Though the MySQL documentation says that they are practically the same).http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html

The error thrown by VS 2010 is:

> Error 1   DBML1005: Mapping between DbType 'timestamp' and Type 'System.DateTime' in Column 'RowVersion' of Type 'Activity' is not supported.     0   0

Where RowVersion is a timestamp for optimistic concurrency.

How do I get it to work between the 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is a problem with DBLINQ, problem reported to Mono DBLINQ team.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [Devart dorConnect for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/) or [Devart LinqConnect](http://www.devart.com/linqconnect/) while problem is fixing by Mono DBLINQ team. These products should work with Mono Framework